# How can I store a Map object in a Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Using Chrome API chrome.storage.local, I can save and successfully retreive an array but I cannot retreive a Map object.

```
var folders = new Map()
//... populate Map
chrome.storage.local.set( { "myFolders": folders } )

chrome.storage.local.get( "myFolders", function ( saved ) 
{
  console.assert( typeof saved.myFolders.size === 'number', "not a Map!" )
} )
```

I'm forced to convert Map in Array before storing. Could I store Map objects directly ?

Comment: Only OWLs can answer to this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't store, or pass with Messaging, objects that are not JSON-serializable (DOM nodes being another frequent example).

And a `Map` is not:

```
> JSON.stringify(new Map().set("a", "b"))
"{}"
```

So, you can only store what [JSON can encode](http://json.org/). That means that you'll have to do your own serialization/deserialization on top of storage access.

Edit: as Simon's answer shows, Chrome performs more elaborate serialization than JSON (preserving RegExp and Date), but the principle still stands: non-primitive objects need custom serialization.

Comment: The serialization is actually worse-than-JSON. Usually, Date objects are serialized via `Date.prototype.toJSON`, but with the storage API, these custom serializers are not called. Date objects (and RegExp) serialize to the useless `{}` value (https://crbug.com/380964).

Answer (score 3):

You can't JSON.stringify the Map, so it does not work out of the box as expected. However, the question was "how" so here it is:

```
var folders = new Map()
//... populate Map

// save
chrome.storage.local.set(
  { "myFolders": Object.fromEntries(folders) }
)

// load
chrome.storage.local.get( "myFolders",
  function(saved){
    folders = new Map(Object.entries(result.myFolders));
    console.log(folders);
  }
)
```

Please bear in mind the API is asynchronous, so the `folders` will be loaded ages after the `chrome.storage.local.get` call ends.

Answer (score 2):

Well, check the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-set):

> Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected. Values
>   with a typeof "object" and "function" will typically serialize to {},
>   with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and Regex
>   (serialize using their String representation).

So you cannot do that directly without converting the data.