# How to store a map in a Chrome Extension using storage.sync?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I would like to store some settings for sites individually and my idea was to store a map with the domain names as keys and the settings as value using `storage.sync` from the Chrome API.

When I try to access a map I just retrieved using `storage.sync.get` I get the error:

`Error handling response: TypeError: result.sites.get is not a function`

In the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#:%7E:text=User%20data%20can%20be%20stored%20as%20objects%20(the%20localStorage%20API%20stores%20data%20in%20strings).)(link to highlight) it is mentioned that data can be stored as objects. I'm not sure what the problem is since maps are objects:

```
var map = new Map([[1,2],[3,4]]);
console.log(map instanceof Object); //true
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605172/how-can-i-store-a-map-object-in-a-chrome-app) I read that serialization is a problem when you try to store objects using `storage.local`. I don't know if this should be a problem with `storage.sync` though.

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```js
var siteList = new Map();

siteList.set('site1', {settings: "foo"});
siteList.set('site2', {settings: "bar"});

chrome.storage.sync.set({sites: siteList}, function() {
    console.log("Map set");
});
        
chrome.storage.sync.get(['sites'], function(result) {
    console.log(result.sites);
    console.log(result.sites.get('site1')); // This yields the error
});
```

As you can see I also `console.log` `result.sites`, this resulted in a `[[Prototype]]: Object` that looks like this:

```json
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

If someone knows if it is possible at all to store maps using `storage.sync` and if so, how to do it, I'd be glad to hear it!

~Naitzirch

Comment: use an Object, not a Map

Comment: *' Even if a user disables syncing, storage.sync will still work. In this case, it will behave identically to storage.local'* leads me to believe that the only difference is the added syncing functionality, but the available data types and serializaition is the same.